# Does destroying a thread destroy the sockects within the thread?

Tags: java, sockets

Do the sockets get closed when the enclosing thread gets stopped ?  I suppose I would have to call close() on the sockets but wanted to be sure.

Comment: even if you call close() , its left to the OS to close them.. calling close() is like telling the OS "Bro, I am done with this socket"..

Comment: @TheLostMind That's true of any native resource, but a point to be stressed is that the socket will be closed asynchronously, after exchanging the TCP signaling with the other end.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - yes... "will be closed asynchronously"... forgot to mention that.. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

No, threads are not responsible for sockets. Sockets are not registered to threads, but to processes. Control of the sockets is left up to the process, but the operating system manages the sockets.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "socket within a thread". So no, apart from the question whether the OS closes them, from a Java point of view, they get cleaned up the same way as any other object.

1. You probably want to clean up manually, i.e. socket.close()
2. When the socket object gets garbage collected, and it is not yet
   closed, it may try to close itself, but you must not depend on it.

Comment: Would 2 depend on the operating system ?

Comment: @JohnCollins No, it depends on the class (does it have a finalize method?) and on the JVM and how garbage collectors are configured.